# UIScrollView with subView Zooming

Tags: ios, ios5, uiscrollview, resize

I Want to implement a scrollview that has several UIViews inside of it. The left-most item needs to be larger than the rest of the items. So my problem is this. Whenever an item is leaving the screen to the left (its origin.x is less than 15), I need to scale the item down from 470x440 to 235x220 pixels. This is fairly simple to implement. The problem is that the item that is moved to the left of pixel 480 needs to be zoomed in from 235x220 pixels to 470x440 pixels AND it needs to be moved to the left by 235 pixels (so as to not cover the item to its right, but rather move into the space that the leaving element left when it "shrunk".

I have tried a few different approaches to this, but I cannot the the animation to look good, and there is a bunch of glitches here and there.

Does anyone have any idea how I might go about implementing this type of feature ? Note that I do not want to zoom, but I want to resize the elements inside the scroll view in such a way that the left-most element (that is visible on the screen) is double the size of the other elements.

Comment: Checkout [Advanced Scrolling Techniques - WWDC2011](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=104). You should find your answer there - at the end of video but it's worth to watch if from the beginning (you'll need to login with developer id).

Comment: Thanks for that link rokjarc! It does talk about zooming, but I am not zooming my entire scroll view content, but rather I am resizing some of the elements within the scroll view. But the video did give me some nice pointers on where to start :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anyone else might be interested, I ended up with the following inside scrollViewDidScroll:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {        
    float contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.x;
    int leavingElementIndex = [_scrollView indexOfElementLeavingScene:scrollView.contentOffset.x];
    int entereingElementIndex = leavingElementIndex + 1;

    if (leavingElementIndex >= 0 && contentOffset > 0) {
        CGRect leavingFrame = [[[scrollView subviews] objectAtIndex:leavingElementIndex] frame];
        CGRect enteringFrame = [[[scrollView subviews] objectAtIndex:entereingElementIndex] frame];

        float scalePerentage = (contentOffset - (_scrollView.smallBoxWidth * leavingElementIndex))/(_scrollView.smallBoxWidth);
        enteringFrame.size.width = _scrollView.smallBoxWidth + (_scrollView.smallBoxWidth * scalePerentage);
        enteringFrame.size.height = _scrollView.smallBoxHeight + (_scrollView.smallBoxHeight * scalePerentage);
        enteringFrame.origin.x = [_scrollView leftMostPointAt:entereingElementIndex] - (_scrollView.smallBoxWidth * scalePerentage);

        [[[scrollView subviews] objectAtIndex:entereingElementIndex] setFrame:enteringFrame];

        leavingFrame.size.width = _scrollView.largeBoxWidth - (_scrollView.smallBoxWidth * scalePerentage);
        leavingFrame.size.height = _scrollView.largeBoxHeight - (_scrollView.smallBoxHeight * scalePerentage);

        [[[scrollView subviews] objectAtIndex:leavingElementIndex] setFrame:leavingFrame];

        //Reset the other visible frames sizes
        int index = 0;
        for (UIView *view in [scrollView subviews]) {

            if([view isKindOfClass:[SlidingView class]] && index > entereingElementIndex) {
                CGRect frame = view.frame;
                frame.size.width = _scrollView.smallBoxWidth;
                frame.size.height = _scrollView.smallBoxHeight;
                frame.origin.x = [_scrollView leftMostPointAt:index];
                [view setFrame:frame];
            }

            index++;
        }

    }    
}
```

This is what it looks like in the end:

[End Result http://stuff.haagen.name/iOS%20scroll%20resize.gif](http://stuff.haagen.name/iOS%20scroll%20resize.gif)

Comment: This is implemented more fully in the following project: https://github.com/kantega/meetingrooms